# Modifying the response object for creating and downloading a document

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've been looking at some code done in C# ASP .NET WebForms and for some reason I really don't like the below code. What is the best alternative for creating a document and downloading it in Webforms, on the click of a button? Should the developer be messing with the Response at all, in this way?

```
Response.ClearContent();
Response.BufferOutput = true;
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0:yyyyMMdd}.xlsx", DateTime.Now));
Response.BinaryWrite(pck.GetAsByteArray());
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in ASP.NET WebForms you don't have any nice helper method to hide this. However if you do it often you *should* make it easier and less error-prone.

```
public static void WriteDownload(this HttpResponse response, string fileName, byte[] data)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fileName))
        throw new ArgumentException("File name must be specified.", "fileName");

    if (data == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("data");

    response.ClearContent();

    response.ContentType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(fileName);
    response.AddHeader("content-disposition",
        String.Format("attachment; filename={0}", fileName));

    response.BinaryWrite(data);
    response.End();
}
```

It will then be used like this:

```
Response.WriteDownload(GetFileNameFromTodayDate(".xlsx"), pkg.GetAsByteArray());
```

Where `GetFileNameFromTodayDate()` is simply:

```
private static string GetFileNameFromTodayDate(string extension)
{
    return String.Format("{0:yyyyMMdd}.{1}",
        DateTime.Now, extension.TrimStart(' ', '.');
}
```

Few more notes:

- `BufferOutput` is `true` by default, you do not need to repeat it. However I'd consider to set it to `false`.
- If you're using .NET Framework 4.5+ you do not need any function to resolve MIME type otherwise you'd better to resort some helper function but do not hard-code it anywhere.
- You do not need `Response.Flush()` because buffering is on and, moreover, you do not stream anything else before `Response.End()`, it's just redundant.